# Shop by shopping options

Tags: layered-navigation, ce-1.9.0.1

Is there a way to limit how many options appear for a specific attribute? For example I want customers to be able to shop by manufactures the total number of manufactures displayed is a high amount. How can I make it so it is expandable by clicking a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find this extension useful.

http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/layered-navigation.html

It allows you to customize your layered navigation.

Comment: check this one as well, http://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/shop-by-manufacturer-brands-extension.html